# vim autocompletion: turn off documentation hint

Tags: vim, autocomplete

I made completion according to article here http://sontek.net/blog/detail/turning-vim-into-a-modern-python-ide and it works fine but one thing abut id is bugging me.
Is there way to automatically close that window in which there is shown all docstrings? Or i have to get use to manually closing it after using completion to complete function/method names?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Supertab, it has a setting to automatically close the preview window. As [Alex Kroll said on Vi and Vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4056/is-there-an-easy-way-to-close-a-scratch-buffer-preview-window#comment5945_4056):

> ```
> g:SuperTabClosePreviewOnPopupClose (default 0)
> ```
>
> Looks like it's what you want `:he supertab-closepreviewonpopupclose`

Add to your vimrc:

```
let g:SuperTabClosePreviewOnPopupClose = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the preview window, you can close it from anywhere with `:pc` or `<C-w>z`.

I usually keep it open: it's small and unobstrusive.

Comment: I have bad (i think) habit of doing few things at once. Vim + vlc + some web browsing makes me use vim in part of screen, and with preview window working space is reduced more :P So maybe there is way to make it open in new tab in background? That work for me too.

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a way to show it with the popupmenu then hide it when the popupmenu is closed. However, you can disable it entirely with the following:
`set completeopt=menu`